# How to send in an object format using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, My objective is to send multiple emails at once.

Here is the API format:

```
{
"email": [
 {
"email": "abc@gmail.com"
},
{
"email" : "def@gmail.com"
}

],
 "subject": "Test Email",
}
```

and i've written in a normal way.

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, subject } = this.state;
    const data = {
      email,
      subject
    };

    axios.post(`/api/Email`, data, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

Don't know how to write in this format.

Can anyone help me to give emails in this way?

Comment: Do you want to send that data or receive it and set it to state ?

Comment: @Muljayan - Hi, I want the emails should be sent in an object format. I mean how api have given for multiple emails

Comment: @Muljayan - Email variable having no. of objects for multiple emails. i want to send emails in that way. Could you assist me ?

Comment: Can you show how the format of the emails object in state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would work with a single email;

```
const data = {
  email: [{email}],
  subject
};
```

With multiple emails, and assuming your `this.state.email` is an array, then:

```
const data = {
  email: this.state.email.map(e => ({email: e}),
  subject
};
```